# Does the @Before annotation in JUnit call a method automatically?

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I have the following test in JUnit:

```
 @Test
 public void getLargestCustId_should_return_five(){
     Assert.assertEquals(5, project.getLargestCustId());
 }
```

However, it throws a NullPointerException, because the project-object is not initialized. This is despite the fact that I have created an init-method with the @Before annotation:

```
@Before
public void init(){
    project = new Project();

    personOne = new Person(-3);
    personTwo = new Person(1);
    personThree = new Person(5);

    project.addPerson(personOne);
    project.addPerson(personTwo);
    project.addPerson(personThree);
}
```

When I move this whole code into the getLargestCustId_should_return_five() it works and the Project-class is initialized correctly.

I thought the @Before-annotation made sure that the init() method will be automatically called? Without me having to call this.init() inside the other methods. Is this correct? Or do I have to explicitly call the method when the class is run?

Comment: How do you run the test? ant / maven / ide?

Comment: I run the test class in IntelliJ, by right-clicking on the class and pressing "run"

Comment: Any chance that you are using `@Before` annotation from another library by mistake?

Comment: It should work this way. I'm running tests in IntelliJ as we speak, with a `@Before` annotation on an initialisation method.

Comment: Can we see your imports re. Before ?

Comment: @RuslanAkhundov: You were right! It was actually the wrong library. Unbelievable! Thank you so so much

Answer (score -1):

From JavaDoc

- When writing tests, it is common to find that several tests need similar
- objects created before they can run. Annotating a `public void` method
- with `@Before` causes that method to be run before the **@Test** method.
- The `@Before` methods of superclasses will be run before those of the current class,
- unless they are overridden in the current class. No other ordering is defined.